# change color on clicked linked span tag

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a span square with other span classes inside. The span square is linked, so everything inside that square, is also linked. I wonder if it is possible to change the background color of the span square if the square is clicked?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Can you please provide some code besides `span square`?

Comment: Can you provide the structure of your code? I can't imagine how the spans are arranged.

Answer (score 2):

**This is what css is made for**, so I would use it before I'd go 'jumping' into using javascript.

I would use the `:visited` selector, which is used to select visited links.

> :visited is a pseudo class selector used for anchor link elements that
>   matches when the href attribute of that anchor link has been visited
>   in the past by this browser. ~[SOURCE](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/v/visited/)

A basic example of this use is shown below:

```css
a:visited{
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  
  <span><a href="#">1</a></span>
    <span><a href="##">2</a></span>
    <span><a href="###">3</a></span>
    <span><a href="####">4</a></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Sarz: fixed (was using backgroundcolor instead of color)

Comment: When a user refreshes the site, will the number reset or hold the color? I need it to hold the color.

Comment: @2bb1s: As long as the user doesn't clear the cache (unlikely to be regularly/at all), this will hold it (unlike javascript options).

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll( "span" );
for( var e in elements ){
    if( e.match( /\D/ ) continue;
    elements[e].addEventListener &&
    elements[e].addEventListener( 
        "click", 
        function(){ this.style.backgroundColor = "#800" } 
        ) ||
    elements[e].attachEvent && 
    elements[e].attachEvent( 
        "onclick", 
        function(){ this.style.backgroundColor = "#800" } 
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a solution that uses CSS and that access directly the target element (if the DOM contains hundreds of  could be noisy)

As you can see in this snippet [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ffundpm/) you can add and remove CSS classes to change  background

```
.square{ width: 120px; height: 150px; display: inline-block;}
.green{ background-color: #11EE00}
.red{ background-color: #EE1100}

<span id="mySpan" class="square green">Hello world!</span>


window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("mySpan").onclick = function () {
        Change(this);
    }
}


function Change(e){
    removeClass(e, "green");
    addClass(e,"red");
}

function addClass(element, classToAdd) {
    var currentClassValue = element.className;

    if (currentClassValue.indexOf(classToAdd) == -1) {
        if ((currentClassValue == null) || (currentClassValue === "")) {
            element.className = classToAdd;
        } else {
            element.className += " " + classToAdd;
        }
    }
}

function removeClass(element, classToRemove) {
    var currentClassValue = element.className;

    // removing a class value when there is more than one class value present
    // and the class you want to remove is not the first one
    if (currentClassValue.indexOf(" " + classToRemove) != -1) {
        element.className = element.className.replace(" " + classToRemove, "");
        return;
    }

    // removing the first class value when there is more than one class
    // value present
    if (currentClassValue.indexOf(classToRemove + " ") != -1) {
        element.className = element.className.replace(classToRemove + " ", "");
        return;
    }

    // removing the first class value when there is only one class value 
    // present
    if (currentClassValue.indexOf(classToRemove) != -1) {
        element.className = element.className.replace(classToRemove, "");
        return;
    }
}
```

addClass and removeClass [credits](http://www.kirupa.com/snippets/add_class_and_remove_class_snippet.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use css like that

```
<style type="text/css">
    span.First span.Last 
    {
        background-color: #BBBBBB;
    }

    a:visited span.First span.Last 
    {
        background-color: #4cff00;
    }
</style>

<a href="#">
    <span class="First">
        <span class="Last">blabla
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the javascript **[getElementByTagName() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp)**:

```
 window.onload=function(){
   var square=document.getElementsByClassName("square")[0];
   var x = square.getElementsByTagName("span");
   for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
      x[i].onclick=function(){
         this.style.backgroundColor="red";
      }
   }
 };
```

[This is **a DEMO Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/32kp9z5j/).

Comment: When a user refreshes the site, will the number reset or hold the color? I need it to hold the color.

Comment: No I don't think it will hold it. Because refreshing the site means reloading the page.